# Line 7:9: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import "./main.css";

function MainContent(){

        <div className="card">

            <div className="card_img">
                <img src="./images/iphone_13_pro_max.png" />
            </div>

            <div className="card_header">
                <h2>"I Phone 13 Pro Max"</h2>
                <p>"Release date: 14th September 2021"</p>
                <p className='starPatter'>"4.5/5"</p>
            <div className='btn'>More Details</div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

My Code is this and when i run the code it gives me below error

> Line 7:9:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

I tried what I know for this but it not solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you put your jsx in the function `MainContent without returning anything.

To fix this do:

```
function MainContent() {
  return (
    <put all the jsx here>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your jsx inside return statement

```
return (
   <div className="card">
   ...
   </div>);
```